# Affine morphism, Harsthorne ex 5.17 a)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\Sp}{\text{Spec}}$
Hello, 
I'm stuck with one question in Hartshorne, exercise 5.17.

A morphism between schemes $f: X \to Y$ is *affine* is there is an open cover $Y = \bigcup V_i$ such that $V_i$ is affine for all $i$ and $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is affine.

> Question : show that if $f$ is affine, then for every $V$ affine $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine.

What I tried : first I think that if $U \subset V_i$ for some $i$ then $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine. If $V_i = \Sp(A)$, $U = \Sp(B)$ and $f^{-1}(V_i) = \Sp(C)$ I think that $f^{-1}(U) \cong \Sp (B \otimes_A C)$.
But it does not help me so much. (And I'm not sure if my argument is correct moreover).

For example, back to the question, I want to write $f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{i=1}^nf^{-1}(V_i)$ where $V_i = U_i \cap V$. The problem is that "be an affine open" is not stable by union or intersection. ( I know counter-examples for both). So how can do it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your idea is right: essentially, you have reduced the problem to the case $Y=\Sp(A)$ is affine. Now, another simplification is that you can suppose $V_i$ to be a principal open subset $\Sp(A_{s_i})$, and so $X_{s_i}$ is affine. Now call $X'=\Sp(\Gamma(X,O_X))$. What can you say about $X_{s_i}\to X'_{s_i}$?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering ! One question first (and I will think about your hint after) I don't see why it's enough to consider $Y$ affine. If $Y$ is affine then by my argument the preimage of every affine is affine. But I don't see how to go from the general case to the case $Y$ affine. (Or I don't see something obvious).

Comment: Let us suppose we have proved the theorem in the case that $Y$ is affine, and prove the general theorem. If $U=\Sp(B)\subseteq Y$, you can cover $U\cap V_i$ with affine subsets, and you have proved that the preimages of these affine subsets are affine. To sum up, we have covered $U=\Sp(B)$ with affine subsets whose preimages are affine: but then, thanks to the preceding case, $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine.

Comment: I understood thanks !!

Comment: And what is $X_{s_i}$ ? (I'm sorry, I'm very slow, I hope it's ok..)

Comment: No problem! Actually, I've been a bit sloppy. $s_i$ is a global section of $O_Y$, you can pull it back to a global section $t_i$ of $O_X$. What I should have written is $X_{t_i}$, I wrote $X_{s_i}$ to simplify notation and to avoid introducing too many letters. Anyway, $X_{t_i}$ is the open subset of $X$ where $t_i$ is different from $0$. When you have an affine scheme, this subset is easily understood: for example, $Y_{s_i}=\Sp(A)_{s_i}=\Sp(A_{s_i})$.

Comment: Ok !! I was thinking to something like this, thanks a lot. I guess I have to show that $X_{s_i} \cong X'_{s_i}$ ? If yes, I think I had enough information for the moment, I don't want to take your time more. Thanks a lot again, your explanations are very helpful.

Comment: Exactly, that's what you need. It is not obvious, you still have something to prove, anyway it is the last step.